# What's the best design approach for NodeJS promised & loops?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise, async-await

I have a PHP script which does a loop (several thousand times). Each loop requests a paginated URL which returns some results in JSON. Each result requires at least 2 further API hits to request more information. Once all this is complete, I'd build this into a packet for indexing/storing.

In PHP this is quite easy as it's naturally synchronous.

I'm in the process of moving this to a NodeJS setup and finding it difficult to elegantly do this in NodeJS.

If I make a for-loop, the initial HTTP request (which is often promise based) would complete almost instantly, leaving the resolution of the request to the promise handlers. This means all several-thousand page requests would end up being fired pretty much in parallel. It would also mean I'd have to chain up the sub-requests within the promise resolution (which leads to further promise chains as I have to wait for those to be resolves).

I've tried using the async/await approach, but they dont seem to play nicely with for-loops (or forEach, at least).

This is roughly what I'm working with right now, but I'm starting to think its entirely wrong and I could be using callbacks to trigger the next loop?!

```
async processResult(result) {
  const packet = {
    id: result.id,
    title: result.title,
  };

  const subResponse1 = await getSubThing1();
  packet.thing1 = subResponse1.body.thing1;

  const subResponse2 = await getSubThing2();
  packet.thing2 = subResponse2.body.thing2;
}

(async () => {
  for (let page = START_PAGE; page < MAX_PAGES; page += 1) {
    console.log(`Processing page ${page}...`);
    getList(page)
      .then(response => Promise.all(response.body.list.map(processResult)))
      .then(data => console.log('DATA DONE', data));
    console.log(`Page ${page} done!`);
  }
})();
```

Answer (score 2):

> I've tried using the async/await approach, but they dont seem to play nicely with for-loops (or forEach, at least).

Yes, [`async`/`await` does not play nicely with `forEach`. Do not use `forEach`!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37576685/1048572) But putting an `await` in your normal `for` loop will work just fine:

```
(async () => {
  for (let page = START_PAGE; page < MAX_PAGES; page += 1) {
    console.log(`Processing page ${page}...`);
    const response = await getList(page);
    const data = await Promise.all(response.body.list.map(processResult));
    console.log('DATA DONE', data);
    console.log(`Page ${page} done!`);
  }
})();
```